# Push Notifications via AirWatch REST API?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, airwatch

I am trying to send push notifications to iOS devices via the AirWacth REST API.

I am getting 202 response from the AirWatch console but the notification never shows up on the iOS device. I have confirmed the APNS cert is good and the connection to APNS is working, and that the Intelligent Hub on my test device is set up to allow notifications. This leads me to believe it is a syntax error with the parameters I am passing in the JSON message body.

The documentation has some string parameters for a notification type and application name, but no info on the expected content there. Anyone done this? Anyone know what the valid message types are and what application name to use to deliver the push notification to the Intelligent Hub app?

Comment: Give more information, edit your question and show your code and what AW API you are using then we might able to help you.